# SQL Query Optimization Suggested Products

Tags: sql, optimization

I will try now to better explain what is the purpose of the following question and query.
Let's assume we are talking about a ecommerce environment and database. We have, among many others, three tables: products, orders and orders_data. The ORDERS table will handle all placed orders and a sub-table, which we will call ORDERS_DATA will store all products recorded within an order.

Following the tables definition, without those unuseful fields for my question:

```
    ORDERS (*id*, date, totale, ...);
    ORDERS_DATA (id_order, id_product, ...);
    PRODUCTS (id, name, ...);
```

The primary key in *ORDERS* is **id**, while in ORDERS_DATA the key is **(id_order, id_product)**.

What I would like to do with a query is to retrive, given a **PRODUCT ID** (while surfing on a product page or cart page as well), suggested products based on ORDERS_DATA table. The query will return all id_product which lives in those orders, where, at least one of these products is the given **PRODUCT ID**

For the sake of semplicity I will report an example. Let's assume we have these ROWs in ORDERS_DATA:

```
R1(1, 1); R2(1, 2); R3(1, 3); R4(2, 2), R5(2, 5); R6(3, 3);
```

I want suggestions for product id = 2. My query will return ids: 1 and 3 (from R1 and R3 - they share the same order id and this order have also product 2 - from R2 - btw its products) and product 5 thanks to the order number 2. Order number 3 will be ignored.

This is the query I wrote, but I'm quite sure it is not the best one in performance and style.

```
SELECT 
    A.id_product, COUNT( A.id_product ) AS num
FROM  
    orders_data A, orders_data B
WHERE 
    A.id_order = B.id_order
    AND B.id_product IN  (*IDs-HERE*)
    AND A.id_product NOT IN (*IDs-HERE*)
GROUP BY A.id_product
```

I've already use the INNER JOIN syntax but nothing change in performance.
The query take 0,0022sec with just one product id in the IN clausole. Performance will decrese exponetially with multiple products id (for instance during the cart page, with more products in the basket).

Thanks.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard - stop using it

Comment: Show us the execution plan. Show us the tables' definitions (including indexes). Tell us how fast it runs now.

Comment: And please tell us why do you need the self-join. What's the purpose of joining a table to itself using (what seems to be) the primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the `JOIN` with an `EXISTS` test:

```
SELECT
   id_product,
   COUNT(1) As num
FROM
   orders_data As A
WHERE
   id_product NOT IN (*IDs HERE*)
And
   Exists
   (
      SELECT 1
      FROM orders_data As B
      WHERE B.id_order = A.id_order
      And B.id_product IN (*IDs HERE*)
   )
GROUP BY
   id_product
```