# SQL Optimized query to get suggested products

Tags: sql, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Query Optimization Suggested Products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552044/sql-query-optimization-suggested-products)

This is a query to retrieve "suggested" products, based on a customers' orders history table.

```
SELECT 
   A.id_product, COUNT( A.id_product ) AS num
FROM  
   orders A, orders B
WHERE 
   A.id_order = B.id_order
   AND B.id_product IN  (-**COMMA-SEPARETED-IDs**-)
   AND A.id_product NOT IN (-**COMMA-SEPARETED-IDs**-)
GROUP BY 
   A.id_product
```

This is the table definition:

```
ORDERS (id_order, id_product, quantity);
```

Example:
    T1(1, 1, 2);
    T2(1, 2, 2);
    T3(1, 3, 2);
    T4(2, 2, 2);
    T5(2, 1, 2);

What I would like to do, given an id_product (let's say 2), is to retrive all the id_prodoct which live in orders where one of the orders's product is the given one.  Using the given example I will suggest to my customers the product 1 and 3 because id_product=2 live in the order 1 and order 2. The other products in these orders are 3 and 1. So I will suggest product 3 and product 1.

What I am looking for is to realize the best optimized query.
Forgive me for my poor english.

Comment: What happened when you tried the things that were suggested in your original posting?

Comment: Sorry for the duplicated post but it was closed because the question was not so clear (complete). So I had to post it again, because closed posts can't be answered.

Comment: Using JOIN (INNER) doesn't improve the query. It's  0.0022 sec, which is pretty same as using old syntax. Of course performance decrase while using more ids on query in the IN primitive (requesting suggested products related to more than one id_product)

Comment: Closed questions can be reopened if you edit them and clarify them. I suspect this will be closed, too. Please add an execution plan. 0.0022 seconds is not slow. How big is the table you are testing with?

Comment: I assume from the sample data that the primary key is `(id_order, id_product)`.